# Weird phenomenon when passing light through a net

Tags: optics, everyday-life

Came across this weird "phenomenon" yesterday and looked everywhere for the reason.

[image]

when placed at a certain point the light illuminates only the vertical strings of the net.

creepy ...

given the light source must be in the same orientation (horizontal/vertical)

I used this:[image]

(these pictures are hideously big sorry about that)

what I thought to be the answer was since the light source is vertical here
more intensity of light hits the vertically oriented strings

Is that right? Cause I'm not so convinced.

Comment: What’s the angle between the plane of the light source and the plane of the racquet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to elaborate on @Claudio Saspinski's answer, consider that for a non point source of light there are always umbra and a penumbra parts to the shadow as illustrated here (from https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Earths-penumbra-and-umbra_fig2_318124646):

[image: Umbra and Penumbra]

For each horizontal string, there is a small umbra and a large penumbra due to the orientation of each string in relation to the light source - the light source is large in the vertical direction - and the spacing above and below the string. At each point along a vertical string, there is a larger umbra and smaller penumbra due to the horizontal narrowness of the light source and the blocking of light by the parts of the string above and below the point under consideration.

Comment: so a way to put it would be the shadow of the horizontal lines are a bit diffused?

Comment: Yes, because of all the light going into the area behind them due to the shape of the light source.

Answer (score 2):

If there was only one point-like source of light, the lines shadow should be the same, independent of being horizontal or vertical.

But in this case, any point in the wall is illuminated, because it is always possible to draw a line from the point to some of the lamps. The brightest regions are that where more lines like that are possible.

The horizontal shadows are brighter because many vertical lamps means many possible lines from any point.